# Divide a dataframe by a number in python

Tags: python, pandas, divide

I  want to divide a Dataframe by a constant but I haven't figured out how to do it. Do you know how can I do that, is it possible to do it?
The dataframe is the next:

[image: Dataframe]

And I have to divide this Dataframe by a constant:

**Constant = 29**

I've been trying with:

Dataframe = Dataframe / Constant

but It's not working

the expected output is this:
[image]

Comment: df= df/constant ?

Comment: Add your code so we can help you further, how is this dataframe represented in your code

Answer (score 0):

```
#create df as with one row and four columns
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': 10, 'col2': 5}, index=[1,2])
#divide the df by constant directly
constant = 29
df[df.columns].apply(lambda x: x/constant)
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a DataFrame with 1 row and 4 columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame([[56.2, 33.1, 76.212, 152.1]], columns=['A', 'B', 'C', 'D'])
constant = 29
print (df)
```

Divide the DataFrame by the constant directly to get the answer. There you go.

```
df = df/constant
print (df)
```

Answer (score 0):

This should just work and does for me

```
df=pd.DataFrame({'A':56.2,'B':33.1,'C':76.212,'D':152.1},index=[0])
constant=29
df1=df/constant
print(df1)
```

Comment: It Works but the Dataframe have more than 70 columns so I would have to add all the columns one by one

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function for the division and apply it to each  dataframe column using apply method

```
def devide(column, const):
    return column / const

df.apply(devide, args=[29])
```